# Can't use LLD linker while building LLVM-MLIR

Tags: linker, clang, llvm

When building MLIR by following these [directions](https://mlir.llvm.org/getting_started/), one of the [optional] arguments is,

```
-DLLVM_ENABLE_LLD=ON
```

If used though, CMake throws this error:

```
 Host compiler does not support '-fuse-ld=lld'
```

My Clang version is the following:

```
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5
```

Why am I getting that error, and how should I fix it?

Here is what I'm trying to run:

```
cmake -G Ninja ../llvm \
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/Documents/compilers/llvm/ \
          -DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=7 \
          -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1 \
          -DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
          -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;NVPTX;AMDGPU" \
          -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
          -DLLVM_EXTERNAL_PROJECTS=iwyu \
          -DLLVM_EXTERNAL_IWYU_SOURCE_DIR=/home/user/Downloads/compilers/include-what-you-use/ \
          -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON \
          -DLLVM_CCACHE_BUILD=ON \
          -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
          -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;lldb;lld;mlir;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt' \
          -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang \
          -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
          -DLLVM_ENABLE_LLD=ON
```

and this is my `lld` version:

```
LLD 10.0.0 (compatible with GNU linkers)
```

additionally `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` has multiple issues:

```
Checking whether the ASM compiler is GNU using "--version" did not match "(GNU assembler)|(GCC)|(Free Software Foundation)":
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Determining if the include file malloc/malloc.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/user/Downloads/compilers/llvm-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_be9c4 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_be9c4.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_be9c4.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o 
/usr/bin/clang   -O3 -DNDEBUG -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_be9c4.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c CheckIncludeFile.c
CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: 'malloc/malloc.h' file not found
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

...

Together with multiple additional errors that are listed in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/STptXwYQ) due to size.

Comment: Would you be able to provide your full cmake configuration command line? Also, the output you get from `ld.lld --version` ? I've just tested the directions you mentioned and they did work for me.

Comment: @jmmartinez I updated the question with the requested information

Comment: I tried building with your cmake flags (but without IWYU) and I wasn't able to reproduce :S . Isn't there any other log generated by cmake? I did some quick test and I get some extra log that would be useful in figuring out the problem. I get `FAILED: cmTC_cc052
    : && /home/.../bin/clang -fuse-ld=toto  CMakeFiles/cmTC_cc052.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_cc052   && :
    clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=toto'` among others

Comment: @jmmartinez I did find a log file and updated the question. But the amount of issues is unbelievably high!